# Workbench Crashes due to connection | Executing update command with trigger and store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-trigger, amazon-aurora

I'm quite a beginner in SQL triggers and stored procedures. 
I've written an update trigger and a store procedure. 
I have two tables. 
First (***contact_table***) contains contact which contains email, phone etc and another table (***status_table***) contains task status and other info. Whenever task status is updated to available I need to trigger lambda function.
 
 When I ran update query it crashes the workbench with lost connection error. 
I just wanted cross-check whether my code is correct or not.

**Store Procedure**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS call_lambda_for_email;
DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE PROCEDURE call_lambda_for_email(IN contact_table_id VARCHAR(255), 
                                    IN contact_table_email VARCHAR(255), 
                                    IN contact_table_phone VARCHAR(255),
                                    IN status_table_id VARCHAR(255), 
                                    IN status_table_task_num VARCHAR(255), 
                                    IN status_table_status VARCHAR(255)
                                    ) LANGUAGE SQL 
    BEGIN
        CALL mysql.lambda_async(
           'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1111111111:function:func_name',
           CONCAT('{"status_table_id" : "', status_table_id, 
               '", "status_table_task_num" : "', status_table_task_num, 
               '", "status_table_status" : "', status_table_status, 
               '", "contact_table_id" : "', contact_table_id, 
               '", "contact_table_email" : "', contact_table_email,  
               '", "contact_table_phone" : "', contact_table_phone, '"}')
       );
    END
    ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Trigger**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS status_table_update_trigger;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER status_table_update_trigger 
  AFTER UPDATE ON status_table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        select contact_table.id as contact_id, contact_table.email as contact_email, contact_table.phone as contact_phone,
               NEW.id as status_id, NEW.task_num as status_task_num, NEW.status as status
        from contact_table
        INNER JOIN 
        status_table 
        on OLD.id = NEW.contact_id_fk 
        where NEW.status='Available' INTO @contact_id, @contact_email, @contact_phone, @status_id, @status_task_num, @status;
        CALL call_lambda_for_email(@contact_id, @contact_email, @contact_phone, @status_id, @status_task_num, @status);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Trigger Fired';

END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm placing the data in both the tables. **Table # 1** ```insert into contact_table values (1001, 'test@gmail.com', '111-111-111');
insert into contact_table values (1002, 'test@gmail.com', '111-111-111');
insert into contact_table values (1003, 'test@gmail.com', '111-111-111');``` **Table # 2** ```insert into status_table values('Task_11', 'Task1101', 'Available', 1001);
insert into status_table values('Task_12', 'Task2202', 'Not Available', 1002);
insert into status_table values('Task_13', 'Task3303', 'On Leave', 1003);```

Comment: First of all you should check if the select function of the trigger works and is fast enough, after that you should check if the json for the lambda function is valid. At last, you have to check if the lamda function works with the json.